# Удаление из массива элементов больше, чем определенное значение

Tags: javascript

На вход функции подается строка и массив чисел. Надо удалить все числа, которые больше длины строки. Пример

```js
function delTheWrongNums(s,arr) {
  let sLen = s.length
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > sLen) {
      let numToDel = arr.indexOf(arr[i])
      arr.splice(numToDel, 1)
    }
  }
return arr
}
```

Проблема в том, что каждый второй "неправильный" элемент не удаляется, пример вызова:

```js
delTheWrongNums("abcdef",[1,2,5,1,10,11,12,34,555,55]) // [1, 2, 5, 1, 11, 34, 55]
```

Не могу понять, в чем причина.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function delTheWrongNums(str, arr) {
  return arr.filter(el => el <= str.length);
}
var res = delTheWrongNums("abcdef",[1,2,5,1,10,11,12,34,555,55]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

---

```js
function delTheWrongNums(s, arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > s.length) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      i--; // !!!
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

var arr = delTheWrongNums("abcdef", [1, 2, 5, 1, 10, 11, 12, 34, 555, 55]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: А, точно, если элемент удален - переносить счетчик `i` на шаг назад. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function delTheWrongNums(str, arr) {
  return arr.filter(el => el <= str.length);
}
```

Оставлю небольшой комментарий по поводу ранее данного примера.

Метод filter создаёт новый массив, в который войдут только те элементы массива, для которых вызов callback(item, i, arr) возвратит true - https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration

В качестве аргумента указана стрелочная функция, которую можно переписать в обычном виде

```
function (el) {
    if (el <= str.length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `return el <= str.length;`